# NVarchar Prefix causes wrong index to be selected

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, indexing, sql-server-2012

I have an entity framework query that has this at the heart of it:

```
SELECT 1 AS dummy
FROM   [dbo].[WidgetOrder] AS widgets
WHERE  widgets.[SomeOtherOrderId] = N'SOME VALUE HERE'
```

The execution plan for this chooses an index that is a composite of three columns.  **This takes 10 to 12 seconds.**

However, there is an index that is just [SomeOtherOrderId] with a few other columns in the "include".  That is the index that should be used.  And when I run the following queries it is used:

```
SELECT 1 AS dummy
FROM   [dbo].[WidgetOrder] AS widgets
WHERE  widgets.[SomeOtherOrderId] = CAST(N'SOME VALUE HERE' AS VARCHAR(200))

SELECT 1 AS dummy
FROM   [dbo].[WidgetOrder] AS widgets
WHERE  widgets.[SomeOtherOrderId] = 'SOME VALUE HERE'
```

**This returns instantly.**  And it uses the index that is just `SomeOtherOrderId`

So, my problem is that **I can't really change how Entity Framework makes the query**.

**Is there something I can do from an indexing point of view that could cause the correct index to be selected?**

Comment: The problem is SQL has to convert every `SomeOtherOrderId` to unicode, so your index becomes usless, and its reverting to an index scan instead of seek.  The only thing I can suggest, and I don't know if it will work is to drop a view over the table, and cast the `SomeOtherOrderId` as an nvarchar, and index the view -- but something tells me you can't do that.  If it works, query the view, not the table.

Comment: @JiggsJedi - thanks, at least I know why it is doing what it is doing now.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, since version 4.0, EF doesn't generate unicode parameters for non-unicode columns. But you can always force non-unicode parameters by [`DbFunctions.AsNonUnicode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.asnonunicode%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) (prior to EF6, `DbFunctions` is `EntityFunctions`):

```cs
from o in db.WidgetOrder
where o.SomeOtherOrderId == DbFunctions.AsNonUnicode(param)
select o
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like ....

```
SELECT 1 AS dummy
FROM   [dbo].[WidgetOrder] AS widgets WITH (INDEX(Target_Index_Name))
WHERE  widgets.[SomeOtherOrderId] = N'SOME VALUE HERE'
```

This query hint sql server explicitly what index to use to get resutls.